# how to insert an element in the beginning when using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to fill an array with the digits of a natural number using recursion. The problem is that i don't understand recursion very well.

```
int fill(long long number, int arr[10])
{
    if(number<10)
    {
        arr[0]=number;
        return arr[10];
    }
    else
    {
        arr[0]=number%10;
        for(int i=0;i>10;i++)
        {
            arr[i+1]=arr[i];
        }
        return fill(number/10, arr);
    }
}
```

If anyone can help in any way it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `arr[10]` will result in undefined behavior, since it's reading past the end of the array `arr`.

Comment: Recursion is indeed hard for those who are new to it, so you should exercise a lot.

Comment: One thing, in C or C++, if you write int arr[10], the elements are arr[0], arr[1], ..., arr[9]. NOT arr[10].

Comment: Another thing, in most implementations, long long can be more that 10 digits.  Make it 25 digits to be safe.

Comment: Your code is using a loop AND recursion.   In a simple problem like this, use a loop OR use recursion.    (For more complicated problems, that may not be true, but for this one it will suffice).

Comment: @user31264  - 20 digits will suffice for a 64-bit `long long`, and 21 for a 64-bit `unsigned long long`  (64 bits corresponds to the minimum requirement for those types).

Comment: I think besides recursion, general knowledge of c/c++ is lacking aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a problem that must be solved with recursion, you probably should not be using `for`-loops.
The goal is that each iteration of `fill()` fills in one digit in the right position in the array, and if necessary calls itself again to fill in the remaining digits. You already have the right kind of structure in your code, but it's inefficient because of the extra `for`-loop. You can avoid it by using the return value of `fill()` to keep track of where you have to place digits. Here is a possible solution:

```
int fill(long long number, int arr[10])
{
    if (!number)
        return 0;

    int pos = fill(number / 10, arr);
    arr[pos] = number % 10;
    return pos + 1;
}
```

In this implementation, we call ourselves recursively until the number is zero. When it is zero, we return 0. The return value is used to indicate where in the array we have to write a digit. So after we reach the deepest recursion level, and return for the first time, we write the most significant digit to `arr[0]`. Then we return `0 + 1`. That means that one recursion level up, we have `pos = 1`, and we write the second most significant digit to `arr[1]`, and then we return `1 + 1`, and so on until we write the least significant digit, and then we are done. The return value of the initial call to `fill()` is then equal to the number of digits written to `arr`.

There are two more issue with this function. The first is when `number` is larger than 10 digits. In that case, it will write past the end of the array. So you will need to add some check to prevent that from happening, or ensure the array is large enough to hold the largest possible `long long` value (which is 20 digits if `long long` is 64-bits). Check [`LLONG_MAX` from the climits.h header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits) to get the maximum value for your platform. The second is that this function doesn't handle negative numbers very well. If you want to ensure it only handles non-negative numbers, change it to use `unsigned long long`. In that case, be aware that the largest number is `ULLONG_MAX`, and on 64-bit platforms this probably means 21 digits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The for loop was just me trying stuff, i shouldn't have included it. I have a do while loop in main() that doesn't allow the user to enter negative numbers. I will look into variables more. Your explanation was very detailed and easy to understand, thanks for that. It's obvious that i'm very new to recursion and coding in general so i will be practicing more of course.

Answer (score 0):

arr[i+1] iterator in for loop will have UB when i=9 and i=10

Comment: Actually the for loop will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to solve it for you, here is how you should think, if you want to master the recursion (which is indeed often hard for people who encounter it for a first time).

1. Your function is supposed to fill first elements of array with digits, and return the number of digits.
2. Suppose that the number >= 10.  You called fill(number/10, arr). It returned x which is the number of digits in number/10 . What should you do now? what should you return?
3. Suppose that the number < 10. What should you do? What should you return?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will be practicing more of course.